# How to resolve unmodifiable replica set state

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

We are using ***mongoDB 3.0***, and our setup uses six instances with one **PRIMARY** and the rest of them as **SECONDARY**.

We were trying to remove three of these using the following command sequence -

```
rs.remove("host1:port") //same for host2, host3
```

Now that we wanted to add those back, there is a weird state that the rs.conf() results in. i.e

The replica set before removal was at the ***`_id:1,2 and 3`*** Now that we have added them back, they are at the ***`_id:7,8, and 9`***

Why does this happen so, and how do I correct the `rs.conf()`?

Also if I again try and remove host1, host2 or host3, they are not getting removed.

```
rs.remove("host1:port")
```

displays the `conf()` value back again, so we are unable to remove them now. Is there a way to overcome from such state?

---

***`rs.conf()`***

```
{
    "_id" : "shard1",
    "version" : 15,
    "members" : [
        ...
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "host" : "host4:port",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "host" : "host5:port",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "host" : "host1:port",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your current `rs.conf()` look like? Do you get any error message when trying to remove a member? It is expected that the member `_id`s will change if you remove and re-add a member so I wouldn't be concerned about those incrementing. Also, what specific version of MongoDB 3.0 are you using?

Comment: @Stennie Updated the rs.conf() in question and we are using mongo 3.0.4.
*Do you get any error message when trying to remove a member?* No, the rs.conf() gets displayed as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add hosts, _id is set always one bigger than what is current max _id. If you really want to "fix" that, you can always do:

```
var cfg=rs.conf()
cfg.member[3]._id=0
cfg.member[4]._id=1
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

Same way, you can change anything or everything in your rs configuration. Remove or add new hosts, change an order of hosts in the list.

Comment: there is still half answered, I am unable to remove the replica set, which is the major problem currently

Comment: You can remove that replica set with that rs.reconfig(cfg) procedure. As I said, you can do ANY change! After change (removing that node), that node will receive this new configuration and will drop out from replica set, because it doesn't belong in it anymore.

Comment: Well the remove part doesn't seem to be working for me, as already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Just rs.conf(), copy members part to your text editor, remove wanted node, copy that member part back to clipboard, then var cfg=rs.conf(); cfg.members=<paste here>; rs.reconfig(cfg);

Comment: that works, but why would `rs.remove("")` not work?

Comment: rs.remove("") don't tell what to remove.. You need to insert nodes "name:port" there to remove.

Comment: I meant the same. Wrote that in the question itself.